# Working with customer-processing-order.php WooCommerce email template img tags

Tags: woocommerce, html-email, email-templates

I've been building myself a custom email template but as it turns out the email template doesn't support img tag

https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=img

[image]

```
 <img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/my-logo.svg" width="200">
```

Does anyone know a good workaround to add img to Woocommerce email template?

**EDIT: As it turns out it doesn't support svg images so I replaced them with JPG instead. JPG and JPEG formats are 100% supported but for some reason images till don't appear in Gmail(working fine in Outlook).**

Gmail console log shows this

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email environments definitely support the `<img>` tag! What you're referencing above is the 'loading' attribute (within an img tag).

However, it looks like you are trying to use an svg, which doesn't have great support: https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-svg/

Try using a jpg or png.

Comment: Great answer and it helps me a lot. I made progress. As I changed the image formats from svg to jpg they will appear on Outlook but if I check email on gmail the images are no there. A lot of headache with this email thing, It doesn't support so many things.

Comment: Weird. This is not a support issue, as Gmail definitely supports jpg. Can we get a look at the final code? (Google: how to get gmail view source code)

Comment: I think occurred because gmail tried to download pictures before it shows them in e-mail but the pictures were not accessible from my domain because of the IP limitations.